# jquery order table rows and 'sub' rows

Tags: jquery

With help I can now order my table row 'sections', I'm now trying to order the rows with in the sections.

This is my table:

```
<table id='sites'>

<tr id="0" data-site="SITE:1" data-order="1" data-siteid="12456232" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE1
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>

<tr id="15" data-site="S:1" data-order="1" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW1</td></tr>
<tr id="18" data-site="S:1" data-order="3" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW3</td></tr>
<tr id="12" data-site="S:1" data-order="2" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW2</td></tr>


<tr id="5" data-site="SITE:3" data-order="3" data-siteid="78565213" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE3
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>

<tr id="21" data-site="S:3" data-order="1" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW1</td></tr>
<tr id="32" data-site="S:3" data-order="3" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW3</td></tr>
<tr id="22" data-site="S:3" data-order="2" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW2</td></tr>
<tr id="24" data-site="S:3" data-order="5" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW5</td></tr>
<tr id="34" data-site="S:3" data-order="4" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW4</td></tr>
<tr id="31" data-site="S:3" data-order="6" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW6</td></tr>


<tr id="8" data-site="SITE:4" data-order="4" data-siteid="36587492" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE4
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>

<tr id="55" data-site="S:4" data-order="1" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW1</td></tr>


<tr id="6" data-site="SITE:2" data-order="2" data-siteid="02365874" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE2
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>

<tr id="45" data-site="S:2" data-order="1" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW1</td></tr>
<tr id="61" data-site="S:2" data-order="3" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW3</td></tr>
<tr id="19" data-site="S:2" data-order="2" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW2</td></tr>

</table>
```

This is a section row:

```
<tr id="0" data-site="SITE:1" data-order="1" data-siteid="12456232" class="site_heading nodrag"><td>SITE1
<td><span id='up'>Up</span> / <span id='down'>Down</span></td></tr>
```

And this is a row within it.

```
<tr id="15" data-site="S:1" data-order="1" class="toggler_row"><td>ROW1</td></tr>
```

The rows with `data-site=S:1` belong to section with `data-site=SITE:1` etc, the rows order should be determined by `data-order="1"`

Using the following I'm ordering my sections:

```
var $table=$('#sites');
var rows = $table.find('tr.site_heading').get();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).attr('data-order');
    var keyB = $(b).attr('data-order');
    if (!keyA || !keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
});

$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
})

$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $(this).attr("data-order", index+1);
});
```

My first question is how do I order the rows within the sections as well ?
This is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/390aprvf/1/)** that shows what currently happens. The sections are ordered, but the additional rows are added above them, not in the correct section.

my second question is can I get the rows order index, but relative to the section row ? I plan to look at being able to move the rows order, but I'll need to know it's current relative order.

Thanks

Comment: I've got part of this working. I have the sections and rows ordered..`https://jsfiddle.net/qxde2e2t/1/`  but how do I add a `data-order` to a row if it doesn't have one ?

Comment: This seems to be working..`https://jsfiddle.net/qxde2e2t/2/`
Any better way to be doing it ?